# Spring Messages Properties file -significance of dots

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC framework for my application frontend and would like to know if there is a way to use it like below:

`my.apple = Apple`
`my.apple.green = Green Apple`

```
my.apple.red = Red Apple
```

What I want is if i try to use the property "my.apple.yellow" which is not defined above, than it should only "Apple" from the first default property.

I have heard that if the property( here example is my.apple.yellow)  is not matched properly , it tries to search for my.apple only , and should find the default value.but I am not able to implement this.

Can some one help me with an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Java properties do not have a default based upon a '.' hierarchy.

You could display both properties so that the colour would be optional, e.g.

```
my.apple=Apple

my.apple.green=Green 
my.apple.red=Red 
my.apple.yellow=Yellow 

#{my.apple + my.apple.green}
```

Notice the space after the colour, e.g. "Green " + "Apple" = "Green Apple"